# Data sets for historical sea level estimates

Tags: ocean, sea-level

I am looking for data sets for historical global sea level estimates. How would I go about doing this the best way? Are there any publicly available resources for this?

The timespan I am looking at are the following: Preferably from 300 000 - 200 000 years ago to today, or from 15 000 - 10 000 years ago to today.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of publicly available proxy records for sea-level/temperature curves, I'd start with [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.nz/) if you want refereed articles but a straight Google search can give you good results if you use the right search terms, like "sea-level over time" gave me some useful [results](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=sea-level+over+time&oq=sea-level+over+time&aqs=chrome..69i57.5407j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8); I'd recommend the Wikipedia [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_sea_level) as most useful to you.

Comment: I have found numerous references, what I am looking for is an actual data set that I can download and work with myself.

Comment: Google Scholar, you want theses dealing with climate proxies, and it's going to be a pain, no-one really likes to give that sort of data over.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have come across usable data myself, I got the data set from PANGAEA ([www.pangaea.de](https://www.pangaea.de/)), specifically [Spratt and Lisiecki (2015, doi: 10.1594/PANGAEA.854045)](https://doi.org/10.1594/PANGAEA.854045).

It ranges up to 798 ka BP in 1 ka steps with a standard deviation of about 11 - 26 m.

This would be suitable for what I am trying to do, but any other suggestions would still be welcomed.

Comment: Well done, I was thinking that you'd never find it freely available as electronic data.

Comment: Yes,it might have something to do with the fact that the researchers didn't do any data gathering themselves, it is an analysis covering multiple sea level data sets.